# Synchronous vs asynchronous ioctl in worker thread

Tags: c++, mfc

In a simple MFC application, I need to have a worker thread that constantly poll an ioctl for an event. At first, I attempted to achieve this using non-overlapped ioctl inside a while loop. The way I figured it is that if the ioctl does not complete io request immediately the thread will transfer control or context switch to another thread(the main thread or the MFC message control loop) but instead it locks up the application.

In a second attempt I use an overlapped and the problem is gone. But it seems to me that the two methods are identical in behavior since I use WaitForSingleObject which waits for the event (io request to finish) to trigger.

The basic layout is the following. Note that following code is incomplete and there to show only the construct

Synchronous:

```
WaitForIo {
    do {
        DeviceIoControl(hDevice,ioctl_code, ..., NULL);
        do something after io request completed
    } while(1);
    return;
}
```

Asynchronous:

```
WaitForIo {
    do {
        Overlapped ov;
        //CreateEvent
        DeviceIoControl(hDevice,ioctl_code, ..., &ov);
        WaitForSingleObject
        do something after io request completed
    } while(1);
}
```

why is the two methods behave differently? Is there something wrong in my logic?

Comment: In what way do they behave differently?

Comment: One locks the application while the other does not

Comment: I wish you would post real code, instead of this pseudo-code nonsense. I'll venture a guess though: in the second snippet, you didn't open the device with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, the `&ov` argument is ignored, the event never gets signaled and the wait is never satisfied, leaving the thread frozen forever, consuming no CPU time.

Comment: Also, what does it exactly mean "it locks the application"? On my computer, threads get preempted if they run too long.

Comment: I the method that uses overlapped structure does not lock the first method (synchronous) does and hDevice is created with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

Comment: The MFC application freezes, stop responding

Comment: It makes no sense that a worker thread can freeze the ui thread.  You'd better debug that with Debug + Break All and Debug + Windows + Threads.  See what the ui thread is doing.

Comment: Why don't you post some real code instead of this pseudo code ? and also why do while loop ? it is increasing your code size in your question but not providing any info. rather you can make it a simple while(1) forever loop. and save one line.

Answer (score -1):

If it locks the thread, it means you need to give back the processor by making it sleep or something like that. WaitForSingleObject does exactly that by default when you call it. I'm not sure about it, but I think that putting null in the DeviceIoControl function made it wait while keeping control over the thread - and so locks the thread.